# how to retrieve values of attributes in XML in SenCha Touch

Tags: xml, extjs, sencha-touch

I want to retrieve data from a xml data source.
But my problem is I cannot get the store by using StoreManager like this:

var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('myApp.store.SensorStore');

Please have a look my code and correct it.

Thank you

```
Ext.define('myApp.model.SensorStation', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: ['Ext.MessageBox', 'Ext.data.reader.Xml'],
    config: {
        fields: [{

            name: 'name',
            type: 'string',
            mapping: '@name'
        }, {
            name: 'lat',
            mapping: '@latitude',
            type: 'float'
        }, {
            name: 'lng',
            mapping: '@longitude',
            type: 'float'
        }, {
            name: 'locid',
            mapping: '@locid',
            type: 'string'
        }

        ]
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://webtrak.bksv.com/mel/configuration',
        reader: {
            type: 'xml',
            rootProperty: 'nmts',
            record: 'locations'
        }
    }
});

//-------------------------------------Store ------------------------

Ext.define('myApp.store.SensorStationStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        model: 'myApp.model.SensorStation',
        storeId: 'SensorStore',
        autoLoad: true
    }

});

Ext.application({
    name: 'myApp',
    requires: ['Ext.MessageBox'],

    launch: function() {
        //------------------------------------------------------------
        var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('myApp.store.SensorStore');
        //var store = Ext.getStore('myApp.store.SensorStationStore');
        if (!store) {
            console.log("Store not found");
            Ext.Msg.alert('Not Found', 'Found not Store!');
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Store found");
            Ext.Msg.alert('Found', 'Found Store!');
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the SenCha Fiddle, you can copy my code into it.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot get the store? The store is something you need to define with a sencha touch Ext.define class, and then the store can be loaded and will contain the data. BTW - it's "Sencha", not "SenCha" ;-)

Comment: @shepsii Hi, thx to your reply. Please see my updated question(at the very beginning). (If you went through the code I wrote here, you would know what I mean any way. It's in the launch function.)

Comment: Also, could you please explain why you devoted my question?

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, that must have been someone else. I'll spend my time helping someone else now...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put `proxy:{}` inside `config:{}` in your model.So, i guess request will not succeed and app's store won't get fill up.